# How to make prisma model work as generic for creating baseRepository?

Tags: node.js, express, prisma

The idea is I pass the model name to use crud operation for all tables :

```
class BaseRepository{
db = prisma
    async  findAll(modelName: "user" | "post"){
    return  await this.prisma[modelName].findMany()
    }
}
```

The findMany doesn't work and returns typescript error and also when I tried to use findUnique or any other function they don't  work also.. how I can make them work?

Answer (score 1):

the easiest way use `switch`

```
async findAll(modelName: 'user' | 'post') {
  switch (modelName) {
    case 'user':
      return this.prisma.user.findMany();
    case 'post':
      return this.prisma.post.findMany();
  }
}
```